I receive an error when I use import SQL or use %load_ext sql
I am trying to use SQL magic to connect to db,
so far i have installed the iphton-sql. but i keep getting this error

ImportError: cannot import name 'escape_string_literals_with_colon_prefix' from 'sql.parse' (C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\xyz\PythonPlus\Lib\site-packages\sql\parse.py)
for %load_ext sql or import sql.

I tired installing conda package too, not sure whats happening and how to resolve this

I had a similar problem using Python 3.10, upgrading to 3.11 resolved it.

i have 3.11 . i am still facing the same issue. anything esle i can do to resolve this?
